# Preserve screen backlight intensity over sleep

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, intel-graphics, backlight

I am running Kubuntu 14.04 on my MacBook Pro Retina 13" (`MacBookPro10,2`) with integrated Intel graphics, and no other graphics chips.

Currently, when I put my machine to sleep and later wake it up again, it resumes running with the screen backlight set to 100%. How can I fix it so that it remembers the brightness from before sleep?

This problem occurs when I am using `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight` to control the backlight, but the backlight intensity is preserved over a sleep if I use `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0`. (But `acpi_video0` has other problems—please refrain from suggesting it as a solution)

---

Further backstory: I have two directories inside `/sys/class/backlight`, namely `acpi_video0` and `intel_backlight`. KDE will automatically use `acpi_video0` to control the backlight because of its `type` (`firmware`, vs `raw` for `intel_backlight`). When I allow this to happen, backlight intensity is indeed preserved over a sleep. However, the granularity of the backlight control is too coarse and the leap between 0% and the first non-zero level is too great, so I would like to use `intel_video` instead.

Searching for solutions to this, I discovered that this is not intended to be configurable, even though the different controllers act very differently. To get around this, I ended up with the following ugly hack: in `/etc/fstab`, bind-mount `intel_backlight` onto `acpi_video0`. This makes KDE use the `intel_backlight` controller whether it wants to or not :) However, it now resets the brightness to 100% whenever it wakes up.

---

How can I make it remember the backlight intensity over a sleep? If you don't have an answer, but you have any ideas as to how I could debug this at all, I would be very grateful :)

Comment: For all I know, the solution could be to control with `intel_backlight`, but write the closest corresponding value to `acpi_video0` upon sleep (and possibly read from `acpi_video0` and write the corresponding value to `intel_backlight` upon wake). Which software would I need to change in order to make this happen reliably?

Comment: For me, when changing `intel_backlight`, `acpi_video0` changes as well, so if `acpi_video0` is preserved, I would think the backlight after resuming from sleep is close to the backlight you set.

Comment: @saiarcot895 Interesting. For me, the opposite happens; When I write to `acpi_video0`, I can observe changes in `intel_backlight`. However, when I write to `intel_backlight`, the value in `acpi_video0/backlight` remains at the level it was before. If I could have the behavior you describe, that might solve this problem.

Comment: Did you make a significant change in `intel_backlight`? `acpi_video0` only goes by integers.

Comment: @saiarcot895 Yes. For example: I set `acpi_video0/brightness` to `1`, `cat intel_backlight/brightness` reads `119`. I then set `intel_backlight/brightness` to `1808` (its `max_brightness`). Now, `acpi_video0/backlight` still reads `1`.

Comment: @saiarcot895 Out of interest, do `acpi_video0` and `intel_backlight` correspond for you both ways? I mean, does writing to either one of them have effect in both places?

Comment: I believe so. I'll have to check in the evening, as I'm currently away from my laptop.

Comment: @saiarcot895 That would be awesome, thanks :)

Comment: Apparently, it seems that `acpi_video0` is not being changed when I change the brightness, and I somehow got KDE's controls to use `intel_backlight` instead of `acpi_video0`.

Comment: Can you try adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`, running `sudo update_grub`, restarting, and seeing what KDE does?

Comment: `acpi_backlight=vendor` did the trick! Now, `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` has disappeared, so KDE selects `intel_backlight` automatically, and this backlight value is now persisted over a sleep. Thanks :) @saiarcot895 Will you write this up as an answer for me to accept and others to find easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to edit `/etc/default/grub` and in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, add `acpi_backlight=vendor`, and run `sudo update-grub`. After you reboot, you should see that `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` disappears and `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight` remains. KDE will then use this to control the brightness.

If the above doesn't work, you could have a script that saves the value of `intel_backlight` to a file upon sleep and restores the value on wakeup. Scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` run on `suspend`/`hibernate` and `thaw`/`resume`.

Note that you'll need to determine whether you're going to sleep or resuming. `$1` contains one of the above four values (`suspend`, `hibernate`, `thaw`, `resume`), which you can use to determine what to do.